# How to feed multiple pandas columns into keras for learning?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

Probably a super lame question, but I just can't wrap my head around this yet.

I have some data that I built for keras model to learn on. At this point, it's basically a single `pandas` column for input and one column for output:

```
X = names_frame_dupless["vectorized"].values
X = np.array([np.array(l) for l in X])
Y = names_frame_dupless["gender"].values
```

And `X.shape` is `(31314, 26)`

And then my top layer is `dim=26`:

```
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=26, activation='relu'))
```

I have additional columns of data in the same frame that I want to feed to keras as input - how can I do this?

What's the right way of passing data into keras:

- extending my single column representation [1,2,3] to be a [1,2,3,`4,5,6`]
- making this more of a [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] representation?

Comment: create x1 and x2 as you've created X and then use np.column_stack or np.vstack and don't forget to increase input_dim accordingly.

Comment: so `pd.concat()` to series/columns and `.values` ?